# Arthmatic operation in sql query

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I am facing a problem while getting the data from the database.

I have table called `purchaseorder` and from that I have quantity column using that have to subtract some amount by user input, and display results through jsp page, help me to solve problem

Below is the code,

```
    String pno = request.getParameter("PONo");
    String receivedQty =request.getParameter("ReceivedQty");
    int Rqty = Integer.parseInt(receivedQty);
    /*String quantity = request.getParameter("Quantity");
    int Qty = Integer.parseInt(quantity);*/
    
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "root", "dinga");
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("Select PODate,PONo,Quantity AS OrderingQty ,(Quantity-?) AS BalanceQty From project.purchaseorder where PONo=?");
        ps.setInt(1,Rqty );
        ps.setString(2,pno );
        
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        //System.out.println("resultset Value"+rs);
        if (rs.next()) {
            request.setAttribute("result", rs);
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("ProcessingActualGRN.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
     }
    }
    }
```

jsp page

```
    <table id="table2">
    <tr>
        <th>Iteam Discription</th>
        <th>OrderingQty</th>
        <th>PO Date</th>
        <th>Reveived Quantity</th>
        <th>Balance Quantity</th>
        <th>Received Date</th>
    </tr>
    <%
        do {
    %>  
    <tr>
        <td><%=request.getParameter("PONo") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getInt(25)%></td>
        <td><%=request.getParameter("Quantity") %>
        <!-- <td>null(1)</td> -->
        <td><%=rs.getString(1) %></td>
        <td><%=request.getParameter("ReceivedQty")%></td>
        <td><%=request.getParameter("BalanceQty")%></td>
        <td><%=request.getParameter("ReceivedDate")%></td>
    </tr>
      <%
        } while (rs.next());
    %>`
```

---

In jsp `<%=rs.getInt(25)%>` I am getting error like

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /ProcessingActualGRN.jsp at line 87
>
> 87:            <%=rs.getInt(25)%>

Comment: @Honza Brabec,@Pillar,@Radiodef,@Lukas Eder

Comment: @ketan,TQ and what is the solution is their any error in the code

Comment: put the code inside `try catch block` and catch the exception. Then we can help you easily

Comment: I already added try catch block

Comment: ok @Santosh Vastrad. What exception you are getting in catch?

Comment: @ androidGenX,JasperException in jsp page but not getting any exception in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <%
        do {
    %>  
    <tr>
        <td><%=request.getParameter("PONo") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString(1) %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getInt(3)%></td>
        <td><%=request.getParameter("ReceivedQty")%></td>
        <td><%=rs.getInt(4) %></td>
        <td><%=request.getParameter("ReceivedDate")%></td>
    </tr>
     <%
        } while (rs.next());
    %>
```

- I got Output I have made mistake while giving index values ...TQ